# Python, how to get the http header

Tags: python, http, download, header, automation

I was making a script to "automate my life" :) but came across an issue that I'm not able to solve.

This python script goes scrapes a page and gets the links of the "products" I need, the problem is that once I've the link to the page of the product to download the pdf of this "product" you have to press a button, and that's the issue because there is no href in the button:

```
<Form name="F1" method="POST" action="onSubmit="if($$('btn_download').disabled)return false;$$('btn_download').value='Invia File...';$$('btn_download').disabled=true;return true;">
```

Looking at the http header when the button is pressed I saw that to download the file it uses a link like this:

```
https://example.com:443/d/vmlz3ovktv2fvxijixczjdagbdnaeamniexu4zypx3tlesibbhuievcy/product.pdf
```

The value "vmlz3ovktv2fvxijixczjdagbdnaeamniexu4zypx3tlesibbhuievcy" changes every day, any suggestion on how to overcome this issue?

Is it possible in python to get the http header and parse to get the value?
Or to press a button and then handle the download?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't solve the problem of "getting the header", but I would suggest using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It's a web browser automation tool and you can set your script to click on the button.

Here's the Selenium reference for Python: [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Yeah,  I've used selenium as work around but I'd love to find a way to avoid it, because I'd like to have no interactions with other applications (e.  Browser)

Comment: You'd have to figure out how the "vmlz3ovktv2fvxijixczjdagbdnaeamniexu4zypx3tlesibbhuievcy" value is generated. Look in the scripts used on the site, or maybe check if the string is stored somewhere in the html.

Comment: I tried to do so, looking at the source I've found these values:  '<Form name="F1" method="POST" action="" onSubmit="if($$('btn_download').disabled)return false;$$('btn_download').value='Invia File...';$$('btn_download').disabled=true;return true;">
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="download2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="jm1bff6uianm">
<input type="hidden" name="rand" value="4mmdryilzybaz5twxfzubrvkoopzm6nw3hyancq">

'  But no correlation with the value needed to download, but since that value last the whole day I think it easier to grab, if only I knew how :)

Comment: As I said, look also at the scripts (".js" files) in the Developer Tools - maybe there is some part that generates this value

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautiful Soup for that. [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.

Comment: Yes,  I'm already using bs4 for prasing the Page,  but bs4,  as long as I know,  doesnt have the capability to press a button. I used selenium for that,  but I wanted, if possibile, something without selenium because it's "browser bound"